# How to create an array of references that includes references to different subclasses of a class

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, polymorphism, subclass

I don't know how to create an array of references that includes references to different subclasses of a class.

Let's say I want to have a 5x5 grid of references to Shapes. The Shapes class includes subclasses for triangles, circles, and squares.

```
Shapes[][] myGrid = new Shapes[5][5];
```

Now I'd like to specify that Shapes[1][1] holds a two-inch Square. I could use:

```
Shapes[1][1] = new Square(2);
```

but I'd like to be able to only put a reference in the array, not an actual object. More like this:

```
Shapes[1][1] = Square(2);
```

`Shapes[1][1] = new Square(2)` works, but `Shapes[1][1] = Square(2)` does not work. Is there way to specify which subclass goes in each element of the array without creating objects of those subclasses? Would it work better if I didn't specify the properties (like two inches) of those objects?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Shapes[1][1] = new Square(2);` puts a reference only, and not the actual object.

Comment: `Shapes[2][2] = new Circle(2);` - even this is right and it'll work. But I must warn you, that having an array of different types, is not a good design.

Comment: Before you can do *anything* with non-static Java objects - they need to be **created** first. Key word `new` indicates that the object of the specified class needs to be created (by its constructor) and reference to this object is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java objects references are already references to objects. If you do

```
Object[] array = new Object[2];
String string = "hello world";
Foo foo = new Foo();

array[0] = string;
array[1] = foo;
```

you are already putting only references to foo and string in the array. If you do it the above way you now have 2 references to each object: string and array[0] point to the same object and foo and array[1] point to the same object.

I guess it seems like what you are really asking is whether you can make an array in Java with elements that are different types and you can't. Adding subclasses to a superclass array upcasts them by definition. Your Square object references are no longer Squares when you add them to your Shape array. They are Shapes now.

If you want to access your Square and Circle objects out of the Shape array as Squares and Circles you need to downcast them:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myGrid.length; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < myGrid[i].length; k++) {

        Point xy = myGrid[i][k].getShapeThing();

        if (myGrid[i][k] instanceof Square) {
            Square square = (Square)myGrid[i][k];
            int w = square.getSquareThing();

        } else if (myGrid[i][k] instanceof Circle) {
            Circle circle = (Circle)myGrid[i][k];
            int d = circle.getCircleThing();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do an inline cast like so:

```
int w = ((Square)myGrid[i][k]).getSquareThing();
```

If you are making arrays this way just make sure you are checking with instanceof before casting because you will get an IllegalClassCastException if you try to cast a Shape that is actually a Circle in to a Square. Type casting can't change the object, only the reference.